# How to remove window title bar without maximizing?

Tags: titlebar

I want to remove title bar in VLC MEDIA PLAYER without maximized.

Is there anyway to solve this?

I am googling for 5 hours but I can't find the answer.

Comment: Hello. this would be a good question to ask at VLC support. Nothing to do with the Ubuntu OS. Sorry.

Comment: @david thanks T^T...

Comment: Did you get a different answer somewhere else? Care to share.

Answer (score 1):

There is no obvious way to control window decorations (i.e., display of window border and title), except perhaps with the Compiz window manager.

You could still do this with `devilspie` or `devilspie2`. These are small daemons that monitor the creation of windows, and do something with windows that match rules you created. This may work only on systems running on Xorg. Ubuntu 21.10 and later by default run on Wayland, although one still can switch to the traditional Xorg display server.

For example, following configuration file, `~/.config/devilspie2/vlc.lu` will cause a window with the title "VCL media player" to be undecorated:

```
if (get_window_name() == "VLC media player") then
    undecorate_window();
end
```

An undecorated window still can be moved if you drag the window while holding the "Windows" key. In standard Ubuntu, this is <kbd>Super</kbd>, in other desktop environments, it is sometimes <kbd>Alt left</kbd>.